Salesforce LWC stuck on first deployment and did not change with the updates
I have an LWC got stuck on first deployment and I tried to clear caches in my browser and uncheck the Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance int he session settings. but still the LWC is not updating. I check the LWC in Lightning components and it has been modified on time of the deployment but still the changes does not appear. the deployment is a success from VScode. see pictures below. what do you think is the problem. I think it is the same form other sandboxes too



You have Setup -> Debug Mode on? Turn it on and one last Ctrl+R (Command+R for Mac people I think?) may help. Worst case - different browser for a day or incognito mode should force it fresh
